obs-studio: connect to an existing dlive.tv stream and record?
Can I somehow connect obs-studio to an existing dlive.tv stream, and record and/or re-stream the stream? Using the same URL as one would for watching dlive.tv from a browser?
I'm a total beginner when it comes to obs-studio (linux), so please  bear with me if this is a foolish question.
The main problem I'm trying to solve is to keep a rolling log of the last 5-10-20 min (say) of the dlive.tv stream so that I can save it if something interesting is observed. Think: security camera. Yes, it would be easier if the owner of the security camera did this job, but, no, he does not want to do it and tells me I can do it myself. But I need to figure out how :).

What research have you done and what have you tried? Likely not the browser URL, but if there's a stream URL I suppose that might be possible.

I have searched all over the web, but I have a hard time finding any answers, maybe because search engines do not understand that I want dlive.tv as my INPUT and not my output of obs-studio. Any ideas of how to find a stream URL?

Don't search regarding dlive as input. It MIGHT not matter what the input is, and your search should start more generic in order to learn how to ingest a stream from the internet. As you move forward in your solution, there MAY be things unique to dlive you can research more precisely.

I understand, I am now using the search "use an existing internet stream as input to obs studio" for starters.There is some talk about a chrome browser being usable as a source for Obs-studio using some Jitsi addon/extension? See https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/how-to-source-multiple-remote-offsite-streams-to-import-and-edit-in-real-time-in-obs.116813/
